# Package Manager Console Visual Studio 2019 Returns New Line

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, nuget

When trying to update my SQL Database from the Package Manager Console in Visual Studio 2019 (latest version) I always get this. It doesn't execute the command therefore it doesn't update the database. I have tried multiple solutions like restarting PC and Visual Studio, even reinstalling it, but with no success. I am always running VS as an Administrator but it doesn't change anything.

Any help is appreciated.

[image: sc]

Comment: You mean it runs the command then puts you at a prompt? That's how command line works. What are you expecting?

Comment: It just doesn't do anything, not a single line of output. It just creates a new line without executing the command.

Comment: Firs t of all this is a Console @Crowcoder , Second -question says that when trying to update  SQL Database it does not update database  but in fact starts a new line

Comment: No, it doesn't. Because the command doesn't get executed, therefore it shows no result in the database.

Comment: If there is nothing to update then it shows this: "No migrations were applied. The database is already up to date. Done."

Comment: [Similar issue](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/add-migration-and-update-database-does-nothing/153196), removing obj folder is reported to fix it for them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay so after more debugging I found where the problem was. In case of Visual Studio, I went to Visual Studio Installer and installed this one too. After updating Visual Studio it seemed to add migrations just fine.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
Update-Database -ConnectionString
```

Comment: Please add some explanation for why this works.

Comment: Maybe it has a problem with connection string